# Plone External Method with subprocess Popen

Tags: methods, plone, external

i have an external Method on Plone that calls a subroutine (another python script) in this way

```
output = subprocess.Popen("/usr/local/Plone4/zeocluster/products/xxx/Extensions/check_login.py", stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, cwd='/')
```

The check_login.py imports a module that it isn't installed on the python installation inside Plone. Here There is the example code of check_login.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python


def login_ldap(username, password):
import ldap

conn = ldap.initialize(SERVER_URL)
conn.protocol_version = 3
conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)


login_ok = False 
if username and password: 
    try:
        conn.simple_bind_s(username, password)
        login_ok = True
    except ldap.INVALID_CREDENTIALS:
        pass           
return login_ok


if __name__ == '__main__':
import sys
args = sys.argv
if len(args) != 3:
    print "Usage: check_login <username> <password>"
else:
    username = args[1]
    password = args[2]
    print login_ldap(username, password),
```

if i call check_login.py via shell it works right. If i call it with subprocess inside Plone it fails saying:

```
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Plone4/zeocluster/products/xxxx/Extensions/check_login.py", line 37, in <module>
 print login_ldap(username, password),
 File "/usr/local/Plone4/zeocluster/products/xxxx/Extensions/check_login.py", line 6, in login_ldap
import ldap
ImportError: No module named ldap
```

I really don't know why **check_login.py** is executed always with the python of Plone instead of the python of the system.

Answer (score 0):

The child process inherits the operating system environment from the parent process, including path and such. Plone environment most likely has been fixed to use Plone installer Python interpreter somehow.

Try:

```
"/usr/bin/python", "/usr/local/Plone4/zeocluster/products/xxx/Extensions/check_login.py"
```

.. to enforce system Python.

Comment: output = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/python","/usr/local/Plone4/zeocluster/products/XXXX/Extensions/check_login.py", member_id, password], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)

It stills return me the same error :(. Also i changed in check_login.py **#!/usr/bin/python** to **#!/usr/bin/env python**

Comment: Then something else is wrong and there is something wrong with the question. What does it say when you try to run this script from command line?

Comment: I enter via SSH and i type "/usr/local/Plone4/zeocluster/products/xxx/Extensions/check_login.py username password" and work correctly.